# to capture mq errors in datapower

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, ibm-mq, ibm-datapower

Backend queue is not available and I can see error in the log as " 2085 : unknown object.

But , the transaction in probe looks success and it has not triggered the error rule either.

Please let me know , hot it can trigger the error rule.

Thanks!
Sreevathsa A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MQ Errors needs to be handled separately.

Comment: Errors occurring on the Queue Manager after DataPower has delivered the message, yes, nut any error that DataPower can "see" will be reported in DataPower logs and Error Rule (if Match is OK) will be triggered!

Answer (score 0):

If the service, eg. MPGW, is not able to write the message on to the backside connection MQ, you WILL get an error and Error rule will be triggered unless you have done/set any code to ignore/skip errors.

You can always otherwise add a XSLT (or GWS) that looks at the latest error code from the service variables.